# how to write recurrence equation for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I'm confused with writing recurrence equation for the algorithm below, could anyone help me do this?

Here is the algorithm:

```
ThreeSort(A{i..j]){
    n = j-i+1; // number of elements
    if (n==1) return;
    if (n==2) and (A[i] > A[j]) then swap A[i] with A[j]
    else if (n > 2) {
        third = round(n/3);
        ThreeSort(A[i..j-third]); // sort first 2/3rds
        ThreeSort(A[i+third..j]); // sort last 2/3rds
        ThreeSort(A[i..j-third]); // sort first 2/3rds
    }
}
```

Comment: What language do you want to write this in?

Comment: the implementaion is not important,I just want the equation.

Comment: Are you talking about the complexity function?

Comment: You are misunderstanding something here. This is an _algorithm_ there is no "equation" that describes this implementation, it is what it is.

Comment: What is the purpose of this algorithm? If the intention is to sort the array, it is not even close.

Comment: There is _no_ "equation", this is an algorithm.

Comment: so we can talk about time complexity for algorithms,what about that?what is the time complexity for this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the recurrence relation of merge sort? Should be fairly straightforward to adapt to this.

Comment: but there is no merging here

Comment: That doesn't really matter, it'll give you a good idea of what's happening. It shows you that you can break down the work being done into the work at the current level of recursion, and the work done in any recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but is too long to fit in a comment area, so I post it here.

Your code is wrong if `round()` ever rounds up. Suppose `n==5` and array contains items `6,5,3,2,1`. You get `third==2` then (because 5/3 = 1.666... gets rounded up) and then three steps of sub-sorting reorder the array to:

`3,5,6,2,1`
`3,5,1,2,6`
`1,3,5,2,6`

You need the middle (overlapping) part at least equal in length to both the side parts, so your `third` must not exceed `n/3` to fulfill the sorting properly. That implies you need `trunc` instead of `round` here.

Answer (score -1):

You must divide your array on three part. The first part is `A[i...i+third-1]`, second is `A[i+third...i+2*third-1]` and third is `A[i+2*third...j]`. After sorting

```
ThreeSort(A[i...i+third-1]);
ThreeSort(A[i+third...i+2*third-1]);
ThreeSort(A[i+2*third...j]);
```

you must merge three part of array into one.
Triple merge looks like a binary merge.

Comment: dividing the array in the main algorithm is not like that

Comment: There is no merging here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but I think the recursive equation for determining time complexity is
T(n)=3*T(n/3)+θ(1)
and according to Master Method:
T(n)∈ θ(n)

Comment: This is a bit wrong since the size of the array per recursive call is `2n/3`.

Comment: @G.Bach: You're right. In fact, the equation is T(n)=3*T(2n/3)+θ(1).But the answer does not change and T(n)∈ θ(n)

Comment: No that's wrong as well, it becomes `O(n ^ (log 3 / log 1.5))` which is roughly `O(n ^ 2.7)`.